# JBoss EAP 6.1 support for Netbeans?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, jboss

Does Netbeans support launching/deploying on JBoss EAP 6.1?  I've installed the latest version, but don't see any references to this version of JBoss, only much older ones (or Glassfish).  Is there a third-party plugin I need to install to get this support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which NetBeans version? For example NB 7.3.1 supports JBoss AS 7

See http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB731#JBoss_AS_7

Comment: I didn't realize there was a point release available for 7.3.  I'll grab it and give it a try.  Thanks!